# On Click with a case switch

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I have a few on click events who actually are doing the same thing. Someone told me I should use a case switch for this so I can reduce my code. But I don't know how to do that in combination with a on click event.

```
$( "#wishlist_top" ).on( "click", function() {
    window.hj=window.hj||function(){(hj.q=hj.q||[]).push(arguments)};
    hj('tagRecording', ['Klikt op "wishlist" in menu']);
});

$( ".wishlist" ).on( "click", function() {
    window.hj=window.hj||function(){(hj.q=hj.q||[]).push(arguments)};
    hj('tagRecording', ['Klikt op "plaats op wishlist"']);
});

$( ".product_size" ).on( "click", function() {
    window.hj=window.hj||function(){(hj.q=hj.q||[]).push(arguments)};
    hj('tagRecording', ['Klikt op "maat advies"']);
});

$( ".product_stock" ).on( "click", function() {
    window.hj=window.hj||function(){(hj.q=hj.q||[]).push(arguments)};
    hj('tagRecording', ['Klikt op "maat niet beschikbaar?"']);
});

if ( $('*').hasClass('404') ) {
    window.hj=window.hj||function(){(hj.q=hj.q||[]).push(arguments)};
    hj('tagRecording', ['Klant is op een 404 pagina gekomen']);
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: I don't see what use a `switch` would do here, because you're not handling different cases differently. Instead, you're handling different cases in the same way, which means you can break the duplicated code into a separate method, and simply call the method from your onclick, passing your unique strings as parameters to the method.

Comment: I agree with Jim.   You may want to combine those two common statements into a single function and then have each click event call that function with the differences sent in the parameters (the two parameters for `hj()` but I am not sure this would really gain you much short of cleaning the code a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you can use a `switch/case` for this, it might not be the best idea. You still need to listen for `click` events on each class/ID, so I'd make a function and call that with the specific string.

Using your code from above, you can make a function like so:

```
function tagRecording(value) {
    window.hj=window.hj||function(){(hj.q=hj.q||[]).push(arguments)};
    hj('tagRecording', [value]);
}
```

Now just use a `click` listener like so:

```
$( "#wishlist_top" ).on( "click",
    function() { tagRecording('Klikt op "wishlist" in menu'); } );
```

So next time you want to change your code, you just change the `tagRecording` function (you can rename it however you like).

Answer (score 1):

Another option here is to use data attributes in your markup. Add the message you want to pass to a `data-text` attribute in each of your elements -

```
<a href="#" class="product_stock" data-text='Klikt op "wishlist" in menu'>Foo</a>
```

And then you can set up one JS handler, which grabs the text from your data attribute:

```
$( ".product_stock" ).on( "click", function() {
    window.hj=window.hj||function(){(hj.q=hj.q||[]).push(arguments)};
    hj('tagRecording', $(this).data("text"));
});
```

Of course this only works if you have control over the creation of the markup.